# How do different representation of the same group act w.r.t. each other?

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose to have two different representation $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(V)\hspace{0.5cm}\mu:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ of the same group G. Now if I take the product
$$\rho(g)\mu(g^{-1})\stackrel{?}{=}\mathbb{1}$$
do I get the identity?In other words, is the representation of G unique?
Since V is the same for both, could have sense to me.

Comment: If $\mu(g)=T\rho(g)T^{-1}$, then your expression gives us the commutator of $\rho(g)$ and $T$, where $T$ is an arbitrary matrix in $\mathrm{GL}(V)$. This should indicate that there are too many free parameters for there to be a meaningful answer to oyur question in general.

Comment: Yes, so there can be different representations of the same group acting in the same space? It sounds weird ti me. I'd probably more convinced with an example?

Comment: Take $G = \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $V = \mathbb{R}$ with $\rho$ being the non-trivial representation, and $\mu$ being the trivial representation.